# SUMIF with Logical AND

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Condition 1: There a numerical value in `Points Received`

Condition 2: There is text in the `HW` field

I need to be able to obtain a sum for `Points Total` if `1 AND 2`.

So in this example, the points total for `HW` would just be `10`, since `1 AND 2` would only refer to cell `D2`.

I will be doing this again for Quiz, but I shouldn't need any guidance with that after receiving the help with the `HW` one.

```
 | A  |  B  |       C        |     D
 |---------------------------------------------
1|HW  |Quiz |Points Received |Total Points
2|HW1 |     |10              |10
3|HW2 |     |X               |10
4|    |Q1   |9               |10
5|    |Q2   |X               |10  
6|... |     |                |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to use SUMIFS as there is no way to test whether the data in C is a number or not.  You can test if it is blank or not but not if it is a number vs text.

You will want to use SUMPRODUCT with booleans to test:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5<>"")*(ISNUMBER(--C2:C5)),D2:D5)
```

This will create an array SUMPROCUT({1,0,0,0},{10,10,10,10}) and will thus return `10`

[image]